# coolant fans on 93 cadillac seville are not working

Tags: cooling-system, fan, cadillac

i tested the fans , they work ok, 50 amp fuse is ok and tested for power to it. ok,  digital display is showing temperature as it rises, hit 220 and the fans do not come on....is there a relay somewhere I am missing, or a separate sending unit. other than the one next to thermostat? 4.9 engine. with 93,000 miles...

Comment: There is almost certainly a relay.

Comment: You could be suffering from excessive [voltage drop](https://youtu.be/DfLyh43iihM) across the fan circuit.